# CakePHP - find Model using association other than id

Tags: cakephp

I'm having no luck trying to bend CakePHP to do what I need.

I have 2 Models, Listing & ListingService.

ListingService's fields are as follow: id, title, listing_id, service_type_id
(So in a way it is like a has and belongs to many relationship with Listing)

When I do a find right now. (Using belongsTo in Listing.php)

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'ListingService' => array(
        'className'  => 'ListingService',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    )
);

$this->paginate = array('type' => 'all', 'recursive' => 0,
        'fields' => array('Listing.id', 'Listing.title',
                   'ListingService.service_type_id','ListingService.title'),
        'limit' => 10
);
```

This is the query that is showing

```
SELECT `Listing`.`id`, `Listing`.`title`, `ListingService`.`service_type_id`, `ListingService`.`title` FROM `listings` AS `Listing` LEFT JOIN `listing_services` AS `ListingService` ON (`Listing`.`id` = `ListingService`.`id`) LIMIT 10
```

This is almost what I need, except that I would like the LEFT JOIN to be ON (`Listing`.`id` = `ListingService`.`listing_id`) instead of ON (`Listing`.`id` = `ListingService`.`id`)

If I use "hasMany" it doesn't even do the LEFT JOIN.

I don't have a ListingService.php model currently.

Please enlight.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I need to first do this.

```
$this->Listing->ListingService->primaryKey = 'listing_id';
```

Is this a hack? If yes, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If listing_id *is* the primary key in your database, it is not a hack, but it *does* mean you didn't stick to the CakePHP conventions. If it is a new project, I'd really advise you to use the CakePHP naming conventions when possible. Not only will this make make it easier, it also forces you to be *consistent*. See [Model and Database Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

I think your belongsTo should be like this

```
 public $belongsTo = array(
    'ListingService' => array(
         'className'  => 'ListingService',
         'foreignKey' => 'listing_id'
    )
 );
```